# JSONSerialization to SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I am trying to use SwiftyJSON with my JSON api data but am having trouble understanding how the conversion works.

Here is a link to the SwiftyJSON Git: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Here is my current code:

```
func newFilms() {

        let apiKey = "12345"
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=\(apiKey)&language=en-US&page=1")
        let request = URLRequest(
            url: url! as URL,
            cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,
            timeoutInterval: 10 )

        let session = URLSession (
            configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
            delegate: nil,
            delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main
        )

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (dataOrNil, response, error) in
            if let data = dataOrNil {
                if let resposeDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[]) as? [String: Any] {

                    self.films = (resposeDictionary["results"] as? [String: Any])!
                    print("response: \(resposeDictionary)")
                }

            }

            self.filteredFilms = self.films
            self.filmsCollection.reloadData()

        })


        task.resume()

    }
```

Here is the example of the new SwiftyJSON:

```
let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
if let userName = json[0]["user"]["name"].string {
print("\(userName)")
//Now you got your value
}
```

My main question is, what would go where it says `data: datafromNetworking`, I am confused what part of the original code should be implemented and how to use it for the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataFromNetworking` represents the `data` object returned from the dataTask. SwiftyJSON does the deserialization.

Replace

```
if let data = dataOrNil {
    if let resposeDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[]) as? [String: Any] {

        self.films = (resposeDictionary["results"] as? [String: Any])!
        print("response: \(resposeDictionary)")
    }
}
```

with

```
if let data = dataOrNil {
    do {
        let json = try JSON(data: data)
        self.films = json["results"].dictionaryValue
    } catch { print(error) }
}
```

However in Swift 4 `SwiftyJSON` became obsolete in favor to the powerful built-in `Codable` protocol

Comment: Have a link or example of a conversion from serialization to codable?

Comment: Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+codable+parse). A concrete solution depends on the concrete JSON structure.

Comment: Ok, so I've decoded the data fine. Problem is now finding the correct code used to use the data. Such as displaying the data in cells or using .count. Not having much luck finding many resources on this for JSON codable data.